# Reading 2 CSV files and using vectors to store the values and then calculate the coefficient. Returns -1.#IND

Tags: c++, csv, vector, coefficients

This is my code I have, which when I build it works and creates the .exe file, however throughout the process I print the function (i.e. mean, covarience, coefficient) and they all come back as -1#IND. Think it may not be pulling in the data from the CSV files correctly?

```
// basic file operations
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>  
#include <fstream>  
#include <sstream>  
#include <vector>  
#include <string>  
#include <stdio.h>  
#include <math.h>  
#include <stdlib.h>  

using namespace std;

typedef vector<double> Prices;

Prices parse_csv_line(string& line)
{
Prices result;  
string datum;  
stringstream ss(line);  

int count=0;
while(getline(ss,datum,','))
{
    // convert string to 
    count++;
    if (count%2 == 0)
    result.push_back(atof(datum.c_str()));
}
return result;
}

Prices parse_csv_file(const char* filename)
{
ifstream file(filename);
Prices prices;
string line;

// This will discard the header line
getline(file, line);

// This will get each line in the file, and collate its values
while (getline(file, line))
{
Prices v = parse_csv_line(line);
prices.insert(prices.end(), v.begin(), v.end());
}
for(Prices::iterator it=prices.begin(); it != prices.end(); it++)
cout << " " << *it;
return prices;
}

//Calculate Correlation of series A and B, then return

/* Calculatethe mean averages for A and B. 
(For each series, add each sample and then divide by the number of samples.) */
double CalculateMean(Prices x)
{
    double sum = 0;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < x.size(); i++)
        sum += x[i];
    return (sum / x.size());

}

/* Calculate the variance for A and B. 
(First calculate the difference from the mean for each sample number. Square each number then divide by the number of samples (n).
If the numbers you are calculating represent a sample of a larger group, then you would divide by n – 1.) */
double CalculateVariance(Prices x)
{
    double mean = CalculateMean(x);
    double temp = 0;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < x.size(); i++)
    {
         temp += (x[i] - mean) * (x[i] - mean) ;
    }
    return temp / x.size();
}

/* calculate the standard deviation for A and B, which is the square root of the variance. 
(This number will tell you how closely your samples are located to the mean.) */
double Calculate_StandardDeviation(Prices x)
{
return sqrt(CalculateVariance(x));
}

/* Lastly, calculate the Covariance of the 2 series. 
(This value can be used to represent the linear relationship between two variables.) */
double Calculate_Covariance(Prices x, Prices y)
{
double meanX = CalculateMean(x);
double meanY = CalculateMean(y);

cout << "mean x = " << meanX << "\n";
cout << "mean y = " << meanY << "\n";

double total = 0;

for(size_t i = 0; i < x.size(); i++)
{
    total += (x[i] - meanX) * (y[i] - meanY);
}
return total / x.size();

}

// Using the calculated values, these can then be inputted into the Correlation Coefficient formula to find the correlation of series A and B.
double Calculate_Correlation(Prices x, Prices y)
{
    double covariance = Calculate_Covariance(x, y);

    cout << "covariance =" << covariance << "\n";

    double correlation = covariance / (Calculate_StandardDeviation(x) * Calculate_StandardDeviation(y));
    return correlation;
};

int main() 
{
    Prices a = parse_csv_file("PC1_A.CSV");
    Prices b = parse_csv_file("PC1_B.CSV");

    double correlation = Calculate_Correlation(a, b);

    cout << "Correlation is: " << correlation;

    cin.get();
}
```

Comment: Post short versions (5-10 lines each should be enough) of the PC1_A.CSV and PC1_B.CSV files, the exact output you are getting, and what you expect instead, so that people who want to help you can run the program and try it too.

Comment: To add this information, click the tiny "edit" link at the bottom left of your post.